# Customize numbers to not show decimal if there are none

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like my crystal report to display full number if no decimal but display the 3 decimal if there are any.

For example, I am using KGS to TON conversion. If 1000 KGS I would like to show 1 TON, however, if 1111 KGS I would like to show 1.111

Currently crystal report giving me 1.000 TON and 1.111 TON respectively. I would like to take out the .000 in the 1.000 TON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if ToNumber(split(ToText(1.000),".")[2])>000
Then Int(1.000)
else
1.111
```

Above solution works assuming there will be always `3 zeros` after the decimal and value will always be numeric